# How much does Ubuntu 14.04 cost?

Tags: community

How much does Ubuntu 14.04 cost to purchase?

Also, are there different versions, such as Enterprise, Starter, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu, The world's most popular free OS is always free.

Once its released you can download 14.04 free of charge.

It will be available in a Desktop version, Server Version, and Cloud version.

For more info take a look at [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/).

Comment: Unless they remove the "skip" link from the download like they accidently did with the WUBI download D: